# Oracle 12g - How to recover overwritten tablespace file?

Tags: database, oracle, tablespace

I accidentally altered the tablespace to add a new file to the current tablespace, but I accidentally used the same name as an existing file. In other words, I overwrite an existing one.

My questions are:

1. How do I know which row of my tables that were missing from that tablespace overwritten?
2. How do I recover that overwritten tablespace? Consider that it happened 2 days ago.

If it helps, the query that I used:
ALTER TABLESPACE [TABLESPACE NAME] ADD DATAFILE '[EXISTING DBF FILE]' SIZE 2000M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M MAXSIZE 20000M;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database will not let you add a file that is already part of the database

```
SQL> create tablespace demo datafile 'X:\ORADATA\DB18\PDB1\DEMO.DBF' size 10m;

Tablespace created.

SQL> alter tablespace demo add datafile 'X:\ORADATA\DB18\PDB1\DEMO.DBF' size 10m;
alter tablespace demo add datafile 'X:\ORADATA\DB18\PDB1\DEMO.DBF' size 10m
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01537: cannot add file 'X:\ORADATA\DB18\PDB1\DEMO.DBF' - file already part of database
```

So something else must have happened for this to occur.

But that aside, if some external operation has munched that datafile, then the only recourse is to recover that file from backup, and recover forward.  How you proceed from here depends on what backups you have, what tool you are using for backup etc.

But if you are using RMAN, then the standard docs have a suite of scenarios that walk you through what is needed.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/index.html

Comment: Thanks, you are right in this case. I then crossed check with the team, and they confirmed that there was no existing file named with the one I created this morning in that server.